# What's a good technique for implementing dynamic theming in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, themes

I'm building theming for my web app, where the user can choose a theme and various elements change color (in real time) to match that theme. For example, here is the theme selector:

```
<div id="theme-selector">
  <div id="theme-green" class="theme"></div>
  <div id="theme-blue" class="theme"></div>
</div>
```

When a user chooses a color, add a class to the body:

```
$(document).on('click', '.theme', function(e) {
  var color;
  color = this.id;
  $('body').removeClass();
  $('body').addClass(color);
});
```

The CSS is where it gets tiresome, because you have to repeat a lot of selectors for each color:

```
/* Green theme */
body.theme-green header, body.theme-green .button-primary {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}
body.theme-green .button-primary:hover {
  background-color: #5cb860;
}
body.theme-green a {
  color: #4caf50;
}

/* Blue theme */
body.theme-blue header, body.theme-blue .button-primary {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
body.theme-blue .button-primary:hover {
  background-color: #39a1f4;
}
body.theme-blue a {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

Using variables in a pre-compiler like LESS or Stylus helps to tidy things up a bit, but it doesn't fix the core problem repeating a lot of code.

Is there a better, programmatic technique for dynamic theming?

Comment: You can use any server-side language you want, as long as it has a way to set the HTTP header for the text/css filetype. I have written stylesheets in C# and in PHP.

Comment: You could use core stylesheet for common styling (layout, fonts) and separate stylesheets like theme-green.css, theme-blue.css etc, then include one of them dynamically based on user choice. The selectors would be exactly the same in every theme, but the color values would differ.

Comment: @pawel Yeah, that's something I considered. The only advantage there would be I'd avoid downloading and loading unnecessary CSS, but otherwise it makes maintenance a little more difficult. I think?

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey using a preprocessor and defining colors using variables shouldn't be much of a hassle. You could generate the theme-*.css from the same source file using different sets of variables.

Comment: @pawel Could you give me an example of how you might set that up? I currently have Grunt as a build tool, and I'm using Stylus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easier to do the color change in javascript at the same time you are handling the color selection. Use a single set of css classes for the colors,  eg `textcol` and `linkcol` and apply them with javascript. You need only add 2 lines of css for this, and no jquery or less dependancies.

```css
a, .linkcol {text-decoration:none;}
.big { font-size:1.2em;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<p>Click the button to change the theme.</p>

<button onclick="colFunction('#808000','#000000')">Green</button>
<button onclick="colFunction('#800000','#666666')">Red</button>

<p id="demo">This <a class="linkcol" href="#">link</a> and <span class="big linkcol">these big words</span> which use multiple classes should be black except for red theme, which makes them gray</p>

<script>
function colFunction(textcol, linkcol) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.color = textcol;
for (i=0;i <= document.getElementsByClassName("linkcol").length;i++)  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("linkcol")[i].style.color = linkcol;
    } 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation**

If you wish you can edit your HTML to include these as extra classes for individual elements, as shown by the `<span class="big textcol">` example below. 
Applying the main color to the `<body>` tag means everything inside the body will inherit the color, except for ones with different default colors (`<a>` being the only one that comes to mind).

**User-defined colors**

Because javascript arguments (parameters)  are used you can create a textbox or drop-down box for the user the pick their own colors, other than those that you define with their own buttons, just called the javascript function with variables rather than literal hex numbers.